# spa wont redirect to login page?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, angularjs-routing

I am looking at building a clientside authentication for my angular app. The routing looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/customers', {
            controller: 'CustomersController',
            templateUrl: 'customers.html',
            secure: true
        })
        .when('/login/:redirect*?', {
            controller: 'LoginController',
            templateUrl: 'login.html'

        })
        .when('/testing', {
            controller: 'TestController',
            templateUrl: 'testing.html' })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/customers' });

}]);
```

When I click on the login link it wont let me go to the login page?
See also this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/TVSnCp8AtBKVfcYdWvN2?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Please update the app.js

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('app',['ngRoute']);
    app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/customers', {
                controller: 'CustomersController',
                templateUrl: 'customers.html',
                secure: false
            })
            .when('/login', {
                controller: 'LoginController',
                templateUrl: 'login.html'

            })
            .when('/testing', {
                controller: 'TestController',
                templateUrl: 'testing.html' })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/customers' });

    }]);

    app.run([ '$rootScope', '$location', 'authService',
        function ( $rootScope, $location, authService) {
            $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
                if (next && next.$$route && next.$$route.secure) {
                    if (!authService.user.isAuthenticated) {
                        authService.redirectToLogin();
                    }
                }
            });
        }]);
}());
```

Comment: when I change the customers route to secure your solution would not prompt with a login when clicking on the customers link

Comment: login link works perfect with my code and when i click over customer link it redirects me to the customer page

Comment: getting an error when I apply your code:Error: $rootScope:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop

Comment: can you send me your plunkr link?

Comment: tell me how can i save plunker after completed with my code,, i try to send you but the link is not showing any update

Comment: just save, freeze and then copy url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54913/discussion-between-jatt-net-born2code-and-hanssieteeuwen).